# How to inject a unique key on every route to a common function without passing it a a parameter in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

in route.js file

```
router.use('/route1', route1);
router.use('/route2', route2);
router.use('/route3', route3);
```

in route1.js

```
router.get('/routeapi', (req, res) => {
formatterFunc()
.then((response) => res.send(response))
.catch((error) => res.status(error.status || 500).send(errorHandler(error)));
});
formatterFunc(){
  commonFunc()
}
```

common.js

```
commonFunc(){
  performOperation(uniqueKey);
}
```

Each api call will have different `uniqueKey` in its header. How do i pass `uniqueKey` to `commonFunc` without passing `req` as a parameter in `formatterFunc`.Is there a solution by using middleware or something.

Comment: You have to write middle ware and intercept the key in header with key and value. like access token

Comment: how do i pass to  commonFunc?

Comment: Can you pass the specific header through `formatterFunc`/`commonFunc`?

Comment: @BadCode Could you please , check the solution and let me know the feedback

Comment: If `formatterFunc()` needs the unique key from the header, then you only have two choices.  You either pass `req` as an argument and `formatterFunc(req)` can get the key out `req.headers` itself (this could be with `formatterFunc()` as a regular function that you pass `req` to or `formatterFunc()` could be middleware in which case Express will pass `req` and `res` to it) or you get the key out of the headers and pass the key itself as an argument to `formatterFunc()`.  Those are your choices.  There are no magic bullets here.

Comment: If you could be more specific with an example of exactly what you're trying to do (show us the actual code) rather than the general and broad and non-specific description (without any actual code) we have so far, we could give you more specific coding suggestions and options.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept header in your request as below pseudo code

code execution will take left to right direction

```
 router.get('/routeapi',formatterFunc, (req, res) => {

.then((response) => res.send(response))
.catch((error) => res.status(error.status || 500).send(errorHandler(error)));
});

exports.formatterFunc=(req,res,next)=>{
req.headers['customHeaderName'] = 'customHeaderValue'; //unique-key
next();
}
```

Hope , it will give some extend idea around your problem